# Defining a default controller for a folder in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hey everyone, I have my Codeigniter controllers set up in a folder called employees. The issue is that I don't seem to know the best way to specify the default controller if only the folder is typed in the URL. For instance, I would like to be able to type in:

www.mysite.com/employees

and have it default to the personnel controller, instead of having to type in:

www.mysite.com/employees/personnel

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How have you specified it in your `routes.php`? Have you tried with:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "personnel";
```

Comment: I have looked at that option, but since we have many applications running under this CI instance, wouldn't that mean that I cannot configure the default_controller route without affecting other apps?

My full URL to the personnel controller is this:
http://www.mysite.com/phpapps/employees/personnel
And I attempted to set the route based on the manual:
$route['employees'] = "employees/personnel";
No luck. We have a bunch of .htaccess rules set up that I think might be affecting the routes. Is there any other method besides the routing file, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using one CI core installation, you should have multiple `application` folders, in which case the routing will be unique for each one. Otherwise, I misunderstand!

Comment: We are using the same core installation, but we have a separate folders for each application inside the controller folder. So inside the controller folder, we have the following folders: admin, surveys, evals, employees, etc. Each of those contains a series of controllers required for that app. They all share the same routing file, config, etc.

How would I configure a folder specific routing file?

Answer (score 0):

Simple - just add an "index()" function

```
class Employees extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        redirect ('employees/personnel');
    }

    public function personnel()
    {
        // your code here
    }
 }
```